# Using SpannableStringBuilder to setSpan a pattern several times

Tags: android, textview

I've a code that use SpannableStringBuilder . But I have many of my pattern in my main string. with these code I just change the last found pattern. this is my code:

```
final Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("java"); // i have 9 "java" in my string
    final Matcher matcher = ptn.matcher(getString(R.string.test2));
    final SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.test));
    final ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        spannable.setSpan(span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    txtView.setText(spannable);
```

I don't know where is mu problem?

Comment: yes, create a new span for each `matcher.find()` iteration

Comment: Have you test how many times did the while loop executed,is it>1?

Comment: Yes, the while also loop 9 times same as my pattern @FireSun

Comment: thank you @pskink, it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to create spans for each loop,like this:

```
final Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("java"); // i have 9 "java" in my string
final Matcher matcher = ptn.matcher(getString(R.string.test2));
final SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.test));

while (matcher.find()) {
    final ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
    spannable.setSpan(span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
txtView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: Thanks @FireSun. Very well.

Comment: @starkshang but what about 20k+ strings? It works very slow.